# Python; Converting a list into separate strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to read from a file I have stored numbers in. they are arranged like so:

> > 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4

I'm trying to turn all those numbers into individual strings.

I've written the read file code and can get the whole text as one string, but I cannot make them individual.

for example the output I need is:

> > var1=1 var2=2 var3=4 etc etc

Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that if you're trying to work with comma separated data files in general, the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module might be of use.

Comment: Any logic behind `var3=3`?

Comment: because im making a graph with these numbers and they all need to separate variables, hence why var3=3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> with open('nums.txt') as f:
        nums = [int(n) for n in f.readline().split(', ')]


>>> nums
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As @Amber noted you can use the `csv` module for this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('nums.txt') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        nums = [int(n) for n in next(r)]


>>> nums
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Might want to `map(int,` as these are numbers

Comment: @HennyH true, used a list comp instead though since it's cross compatible

Comment: Depending on one's definition of robust: `list(map(int, next(r, [])))` (or similar listcomp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the variables you are going to use eg. var1 .. var10 and if you always expect 10 numbers in the input file, you can have a simple assignment like below to get the values assigned inside your program variables

```
s = "1, 2, 4" # s can be a line read from a file
(var1, var2 ,var3) = [i.strip() for  i in s.split(',')]
```

if the assignment is not balanced(ie, less/more input values than number of variables) you will get the error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Other efficient ways exists

- you can use dict keys and values to hold data and pass it to the graph method to plot it
- you can use graph class's instance attributes to hold data and call the graph method of the class (if the graph which you are trying is defined as a class)

[similar post](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/dynamic-variable-declaration-140173.html)